# SQLITE select unique rows

Tags: sqlite

I have a table where rows appear to be "duplicates" but they are actually not (they have different date).

Suppose each record has a column A that is supposed to be unique. However due to this column A could or could not appear again later with updated information (with column A unchanged), it is no longer unique even when it should be.

Therefore I want the table with latest information only. Currently this table contains 500k entries, however the "true" number of unique entries is less than half of it.

I have tried

```
SELECT *
  FROM TABLE
    WHERE A = A  
    AND Date = (SELECT MAX(Date) from TABLE)
    ORDER BY DATE
```

However this only returns 2 results. How do I achieve that?

Comment: Please edit the question and clarify.  1) What do you mean by "property"?  Do you mean a table *column*?  2) Words like "unique" and "duplicate" mean very specific things when working with a database.  A column cannot have unique values but also have a values that "could or could not appear again".  Either it is unique or it is not.  If it can reappear, then is it *not* unique.  Note that it is possible to have composite columns (more than one combined) that form unique values.

Comment: `WHERE A = A` is an equality operation.  Such a statement is **always** true unless the variable is qualified using different table/query prefix.  This statement is comparing values from *the same row* and so it will not auto-magically determine that you meant to compare values from different rows.  However, you are on the right track with a subquery, but the subquery should also include the column A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subquery on the date is the correct idea, but you must include the column A in the subquery and relate it back to the main table.  I prefer to use explicit joins rather than embedding the subquery in the WHERE statement.  This is usually more efficient anyway.

```
SELECT TABLE.*
FROM TABLE INNER JOIN  
     (SELECT A, MAX(Date) AS MaxDate FROM TABLE GROUP BY A) AS latest
     ON TABLE.A = latest.A AND TABLE.date = latest.MaxDate 
ORDER BY A, date
```

Or even better, I prefer CTE (Common Table Expression) syntax, since it makes the individual queries easier to read:

```
WITH latest AS (
    SELECT A, MAX(Date) AS MaxDate
    FROM TABLE 
    GROUP BY A
)
SELECT TABLE.*
FROM TABLE INNER JOIN latest
     ON TABLE.A = latest.A AND TABLE.date = latest.MaxDate 
ORDER BY TABLE.A, TABLE.date
```

---

#### Comparison to other answer

The answer by MikeT relies on a [non-standard feature](https://www.sqlite.org/quirks.html#aggregate_queries_can_contain_non_aggregate_result_columns_that_are_not_in_the_group_by_clause) of sqlite.  That is okay of itself as long as you are aware that the solution is not compatible with other databases engines/servers and SQL dialects.

The next possible gotcha really relies on your actual data and table schema (neither of which you shared in the question details).  If your data allows multiple rows with the *same date* for the a single `A` column value, then the conditions in your question are not enough to definitively remove all duplicates.  You would need to identify another column by which to resolve any remaining duplicates, but once again your question did not do that.

However, in testing, I found that my solution allows unresolved duplicates to remain in the results.  MikeT's solution eliminate all duplicates, but it does so by arbitrarily excluding one of those duplicates.  There are ways to fix either solution to definitely select which duplicate to keep, but I will not even attempt that unless you post actual data and the table schema so that my answer is not just mere guessing.  I'm glad that my answer was useful thus far, but you need to understand your data better (than reveal in the question) to ensure what solution is actually best.

#### Bonus

Against my better judgement to just keep expanding on answers... since you should really research this separately... here's an example of how you would continue joining this with other queries...

```
WITH latest AS (
       SELECT A, MAX(Date) AS MaxDate
       FROM TABLE 
       GROUP BY A
    ),
    firstResults AS (
       SELECT TABLE.*
       FROM TABLE INNER JOIN latest
            ON TABLE.A = latest.A AND TABLE.date = latest.MaxDate 
       ORDER BY TABLE.A, TABLE.date
    )
SELECT otherTable.*
FROM firstResults JOIN otherTable
     ON firstResults.A = otherTable.A
WHERE somecondition = 'foobar'
```

Comment: The other answer solution also works however somehow it was very slow. Your solution seems to be much more efficient so I changed accepted answer.

Comment: Like I wrote in the answer that it is more efficient, placing the subquery in the join executes it once and then joins the two together.  Any time that you see a subquery in the WHERE clause and/or select list, it is possible that the subquery must be executed for every single row.  Sometimes the database engine can optimize such queries, but writing more efficient code (especially when it is easier to write and read) is better.

Comment: In my tests, I also get that my answer returns different results.  I'm still analyzing the situation, but I was already suspicious of the other solution anyway.  It is either not valid or relies on a peculiar behavior of sqlite, because it should not be allowing non-aggregate or grouped columns in an aggregate query... but it is.

Comment: Sorry for asking again. Now is it possible to do a compound query based on this? For example, Select "your solution query" and inner join it with something else? Or do I have to create a table for it.

Comment: You can either put the solution query in parenthesis as a subquery; or using the CTE version, you can convert it into another [named CTE](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html) also and reference it within another query.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach if you're using a somewhat recent version of sqlite (3.25 or newer), using the `row_number()` window function to rank groups of the same `a` value by date and picking the first one:

```
WITH cte AS
 (SELECT a, date, row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY a ORDER BY date DESC) AS rn
  FROM yourtable)
SELECT a, date
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```

---

One important thing to note since I noticed you mentioning another answer was slow is that an index on `mytable(a, date DESC)` will be needed for this query for best results, and an index on `mytable(a, date)` will speed up the other answers given.

Answer (score 0):

I believe, if I understand what you have written, that you could use :-

```
SELECT a,max(date), other FROM mytable GROUP BY a ORDER BY date;
```

- note that the other column represents other columns (if present)
- **However**, the **other** column **will be an arbritary value** (from one of the grouped columns) which may well be the required value (in the example it is).

As per :-

> Each expression in the result-set is then evaluated once for each
>   group of rows. If the expression is an aggregate expression, it is
>   evaluated across all rows in the group. Otherwise, it is evaluated
>   against a single arbitrarily chosen row from within the group. If
>   there is more than one non-aggregate expression in the result-set,
>   then all such expressions are evaluated for the same row.

[SQL As Understood By SQLite - **SELECT**](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html)

More correctly, to eliminate an arbritary value(sic) for the **other** column, you could use :-

```
SELECT 
    a /* will always be the same and isn't arbritary */,
    max(date) /* will be the maximum data */ AS date,
    (SELECT other FROM mytable WHERE a = m.a AND date = m.date) AS other
FROM mytable AS m /* AS m allows the outer query to be distinguished from the inner query */ 
GROUP BY a /* this effectivel removes duplicates on the a column */
ORDER BY date 
;
```

- The example below appears to produce the same result.

## Example :-

Using the following to populate the table with some generated testing data :-

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mytable (a TEXT, date TEXT, other);
WITH cte(count,a,date,other) AS 
    (
        SELECT 1,1,date('now','+'||(random() % 30)||' days'),'other1'
        UNION ALL SELECT count+1,abs(random()) % 20,date('now','+'||(abs(random()) % 30)||' days'), 'other'||(count+1) FROM cte LIMIT 100

INSERT INTO mytable (a,date,other) SELECT a,date,other FROM cte 
;
SELECT * FROM mytable ORDER BY DATE DESC;
```

in this case :-

[image]

- Highlighted rows being those required to be extracted.

Then after the above has been run the following is run

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE  a = a  AND  date = (SELECT MAX(date) FROM mytable);
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE  /*a = a  AND*/  date = (SELECT MAX(date) FROM mytable);

/* Will only select 1 row per unique value of a BUT other will be an arbritary value not necessairlly the latest */
SELECT a,max(date), other FROM mytable GROUP BY a /* group by effectively display unique */; 

SELECT 
    a /* will always be the same and isn't arbritary */,
    max(date) /* will be the maximum data */ AS date,
    (SELECT other FROM mytable WHERE a = m.a AND date = m.date) AS other
FROM mytable AS m
GROUP BY a
;
```

The first two results show that a = a does nothing as it will always be true.

The thrid query produces (unordered) :-

[image]

- Note ticks assigned by checking the value of other from the previous result.

  - In this case this shorter query works OK even though values of other are arbritary values (they aren't really as it depends upon how the query planner plasn the query).

The fourth, the more correct, produces the same results :-

[image]

Result 2 (your orignal query) and 3 (original without a = a) produce :-

[image]

and :-

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I was thinking along the same thing of using group by and max(date). However I was not sure if max(date) returns the correct value of the row or just the date column itself. However, what is " :-" stands for?

Comment: max(date) as it's an aggregate function returns the correct value (see quote from SQLite documentations) BUT it's the **other** column (any other columns) that may not return the correct value and hence the second more complex example that uses a subquery to get the correct value for the **other** column. In this case they both queries produce the same results *(but may not and may not in the future e.g. an analyze would have the potential of changing the row used)*.

Comment: I see that sqlite allows non-aggregate, non-grouped columns in an aggregate query, according to #6 in https://www.sqlite.org/quirks.html.  However, just as it says on the same page, that is a very non-standard and peculiar behavior, not a great feature to rely upon when the standard syntax is not any more complex and is compatible with other databases and SQL dialects.  I am also getting a different number of returned rows using the table and data from your answer.  I have not determined yet why the difference, but I'll put my wager on the standard SQL syntax.

Comment: I found the difference.  On my system, the random insert from your answer generated two rows with the same `A` and `date` values.  Your solution chooses a single arbitrary row from any remaining duplicate rows.  My solution returns all matches for any remaining duplicates.  In one sense your solution truly removes duplicates from the result, but it does so by *arbitrarily excluding some rows*.  Only the OP can judge for the OP's data, but I personally would rather be aware of such remaining duplicates so that I could refine my queries rather than just excluding random rows in ignorance.

Comment: Further, the second query which was meant to eliminate arbitrary selection did *nothing to actually avoid an arbitrary selection*.  If the subquery returns multiple rows, it still just chooses one of those rows.  Since there is no ORDER BY in the subquery then the selection of that row is still technically arbitrary.  Adding an ORDER BY clause appears to force it to select the first row in the results in a controlled manner.